# How can I adjust the baseline of a checkbox label?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a checkbox with a label. With the system font, the label is nicely aligned with the checkbox. With the font I want to use (Helvetica Neue Light), the label is too low:

[image: problem screenshot]

How can I adjust the baseline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue in a different way.You can use 2 UI Controls 
1) Check Box
2) Label
Align the label based on your check box and put your check box over the label ( Increase the width of your check box and cover the label ) . So you will get user interaction over the label area also.

Comment: I didn’t want to split the control because I would lose the click-label-to-toggle behaviour, but resizing the checkbox is a nice hack. I guess the only problem that remains is accessibility. Thanks!